# How much CPU usage is normal for RealTime electron APP

Tags: node.js, performance, electron, cpu-usage

I wrote a electron app for a device from aliexpress (simple spectrum analyzer), and I feed the data to the app through some dlls etc. That is not that important, but just so you know what it is.
Important is, that it **goes to the app as JSON and the app renders it using lightning chart.js**.

My questions is, how much CPU should real-time app like this take? Mine sits around 19% on Ryzen5 2600, which to me seems like a lot and most of the CPU is taken by the event handler in the renderer process alone, even if I remove the rendering part on the chart component and just transfer the data to the renderer from my forked process through the main process the usage is high. I am new to javascript so I tried doing 30s performance snapshot from devtools and I am not sure if it helped me or not. [Summary of performance recording](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgqQp.png)

Is there a better solution to transfer large data from forked process to the renderer without compromising on security by turning nodeIntegration on? The data are a Buffer of 65k bytes which I then convert to the JSON in the forked process and pass through all the IPC to the renderer. I need the forked process so the app is not blocked if there is connection issue between the device and the app.

Comment: CPU usage all depends on the application. If this is all your application does, do you need a forked / child process to interface with the DLL's? Can the main process do it instead? It still won't block your render process. Once the main process receives the JSON data, process there and then only forward the needed data onto the render process for display. The data refresh rate of the UI only needs to be 30 - 60 times per second. That is all the human eye can see. If you need a higher resolution than that, record it in the main thread for stop analysis / IPC transfer / display later on.

Comment: I have the set Interval on 20ms which is 50FPS so that should be ok. I tried doing all of that in main but when I disconnect the device the reconnect mechanism kicks in and the kernel32 WaitingForObject always freezes the main thread for few seconds (that is the reconnect mechanism) since it is trying to check if the device is sending data. When I do that in main the renderer freezes aswell.... I thought it makes sence since main handles all renderer windows etc.

Comment: Just out of interest then, is your "forked process" a [Node Child Process](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/child_process.html) of the main thread? I have never heard of a main process freezing a render process, unless you just mean the IPC data transfer (because there is no data to transfer - connecting...). Veteran Electron app users have always stated that Electron is CPU hungry. If you are doing a lot of big IPC transfers, then perhaps yes, it will load down the CPU. You appear to have a good CPU though. I don’t know the use of L1 / L2 caches with Electron.

Comment: That is probably it! I pass the object through IPC with 4 arrays with 5000 numbers each.  (so around 2000nums).I am not expert and I still study CS so I am not sure about the "largeness" of this value. But I have no idea how to transfer it without using IPC.

Comment: I don't think there is any other way then. IPC it is. Next step would be too micro-optimise. 4 arrays x 5,000 numbers or 1 array x 20,000 numbers. Do IPC message need to connect, negotiate, etc like a http request? I don’t know off the top of my head. If not, then cool. If so, then perhaps larger messages is the way to go, if possible? Some research may be needed.